# Count how many times a word occurred in Select statement

Tags: sql-server

This question has been asked many times in this forum, yet I have not found the solution I am after.
Essentially I want this SAS solution

```
Select CNT=count(Rules ,'Section');
```

to be translated into SQL, and I am just surprised that there seems to be nowhere near a neat solution like SAS presents.
The closest I got to is:

```
Select  DATALENGTH([Rules])-  DATALENGTH(replace([Rules], 'Section', ''))  as CNT                                    
FROM [M].[dbo].[file]
```

But it still does NOT count how often the word 'Section' occurred in the variable [Rules]- (I am actually here not even sure what it counts as I cannot work it out). The variable / column [Rules] is a varchar which can have many Section description. I simply need a count of these sections. Hence I need to count the word Section in [Rules]. I am genuinely stuck with this.

An example for how [Rules] looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query:

```
Select  DATALENGTH([Rules])-  DATALENGTH(replace([Rules], 'Section', ''))  as CNT
FROM [M].[dbo].[file]
```

What this does is it takes the length of `Rules` and subtracts from that the length of the string after you *remove* each instance of the word `Section`.

This is a less-than-intuitive way to count the presence of *a single character* within a string but, when you replace a word that has 7 letters with an empty space, you're going to subtract 7 from the length for every instance of the word. So if the word appears once, the difference will be 7; when it appears twice, the difference will be 14; and so on. Illustration:

```
a: This is a section here <== len = 22
   ----------------------

b: This is a here <= after replace, len = 15
   --------------

len(a) - len(b) = 22 - 15 = 7
```

You need to account for this by only subtracting *one* from the length for each instance of the word, insted of *seven*.

One way is to change your query to divide the difference by the length of the string you removed (and I use `LEN` instead of `DATALENGTH` because the latter behaves differently for `nvarchar`):

```
SELECT (LEN([Rules])-LEN(replace([Rules], 'Section', ''))) / LEN('Section') AS CNT
-----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  FROM [dbo].[file];
```

You could also -- and I don't recommend this because wow this is not self-documenting at all -- replace the 7-letter word with a 6-letter word:

```
SELECT (LEN([Rules])-LEN(replace([Rules], 'Section', '6chars'))) AS CNT
------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
  FROM [dbo].[file];
```